# Chrome extension: How to inject HTML into any tab w/o using <all_urls>

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json

I am trying to inject a content script to the current tab of the user once the timer is done. Thus, my manifest is:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.5.1.min.js", "flipclock-min.js", "content.js"],
    "css": ["normalize.min.css", "styles2.css", "flipclock.css", "css.css"]
}]
```

According to web store publishing process:

- Broad Host Permissions

> Instead of requesting broad host permissions, consider using the
> activeTab permission, or specify the sites that your extension needs
> access to. Both options are more secure than allowing full access to
> an indeterminate number of sites, and they may help to minimise review
> times.
>
> The activeTab permission allows access to a tab in response to an
> explicit user gesture.

```
{
...
"permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

It makes sense for me to use activeTab instead. However, as they mentioned, I can use it in permission not content_scripts or else I would get:

```
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[1]': Missing scheme separator.
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activeTab` won't work on timer fully automatically because it needs an **explicit user action**: the user must click your extension icon (or interact via a [commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) hotkey, a [contextMenus API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) menu, or an [omnibox API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox) keyword, more info in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)) to start or set the timer.

Through such user action `activeTab` will grant access to the current tab so your background script can use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject the scripts (use one call per each script).

And, remove `content_scripts` in manifest.json.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful insights. Just to make sure, does an explicit user action need be initiated in every new tab that's opened or no once the user has made an explicit user action that tab is permitted once for all or no once any permission is given to "any" tab, all the tabs will have permission? I am hoping the last would be the case, as in my case the user either case has to initiate the timer, but then would like the content script to be injected at any tab "automatically" once timer is done.

Comment: Lastly, even when I completely took out content script from manifest, the web store still asked me to justify my hosting permission even after restarting the process. Is there a reason why?

Comment: 1) See "activeTab will grant access to the current tab" in my answer. 2) Sounds like a separate question so make sure to include [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: 1) I fully understand that but just want to make sure whether "current tab" is static or dynamic. In other words, if user gives access to current tab (A) & now is on tab (B) which is the "new" current, does B have access or not with the `activeTab` permission?

Comment: B) my sincerest apologies. I will make sure that's another post.

Comment: There's only one current tab at the time when the permission is granted. The key word here is "tab" (meaning the tab's contents) not "current".

Comment: Gotchu, so B won't have permission?

Comment: No, it's not a ticket that you can pass to a friend.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks again :)